# ¿Como muestro codigo de cualquier lenguaje en una pagina web?

Tags: php, html

Estoy haciendo un blog con Bootstrap (para ahorrarme tiempo en el diseño) y con php.
Lo que quiero es ir publicando codigos de programación (php, jquery, html, css, java, etc) y no se como hacer que se muestre en la página.

Comment: Mira aquí: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/code/ Está en inglés, pero los ejemplos se entienden perfectamente.

Comment: Si lo quieres con resaltado de sintaxis, puedes probar syntax highlighter o highlight.js. si además quieres editar, entonces  CodeMirror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas.

Puedes usar [google Pretify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), que es el resaltado de código que utiliza [StackOverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Este es el ejemplo que hay en el mismo repositorio del script [<ejemplo>](https://rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/examples/quine.html).

Otro ejemplo es:

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js?autoload=true&skin=desert"></script>


<h1>Ejemplo de código</h1>
<p>
El contenido que está abajo está formateado.
</p>

<p>La etiqueta <code>&lt;pre&gt;</code>
está formateada por que tiene <code>class="prettyprint"</code> y por que se incluye una librería javascript que genera la estructura necesaria para mostar el código.
</p>

<?prettify lang=java linenums=true?>
<pre class="prettyprint" >
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double angulo = Math.toRadians(60),
                calcularPorSerie = serieTaylor(angulo),
                calcularPorMath = Math.cos(angulo);

        System.out.println("Serie: " + calcularPorSerie);
        System.out.println("Cos: " + calcularPorMath);
    }

    static double serieTaylor(double x) {
        double sumando, sumatoria = 0, precision = 0.0001d;

        // limite superior, iteracion de la sumatoria
        int n = 0; 

        do {
            sumando = Math.pow(-1, n) / factorial(2 * n) * Math.pow(x, 2 * n);
            sumatoria = sumatoria + sumando;
            n = n + 1;
        } while (Math.abs(sumando) > precision);

        return sumatoria;
    }

    static double factorial(int numero) {
        double factorial = 1.0d;

        while (numero != 0) {
            factorial *= numero--;
        }

        return factorial;
    }
}</pre>
```